# SimpleMembership, why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nuget, simplemembership, package-managers

Maybe I am new to the SimpleMembership thing,  but I went through many sites, including stackoverflow, everyone said SimpleMembership is an easier approach.

The biggest question mark for me is, why do we have to use Package Manager Console for updating database? I don't get the idea, I mean, I can edit the database and add the code manually, it's all working properly, but when I use the Package Manager Console, it didn't complain, but it just do not update the table structures as the code I am putting in, even I am copying and pasting the code from the websites:
eg. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-entity-framework-scaffolding-and-migrations

I mean, what is the point? Would love to know what others think about the Package Manager Console, is this necessary? is this really "easier" like all the articles are saying?

Thanks

Comment: `everyone said SimpleMembership is an easier approach` easier than what, everything else? Besides that I must say, using the console to update/setup/reset the database takes a little getting used to in the start maybe, but I found it quite fun to use!

Comment: You're confusing multiple concepts.  Updating the database is done for Entity Framework Migrations.  This is a process that's used to script out and make automatic changes to databases so that it can be repeated in production or other environments.  SImpleMembership is a MembershipProvider that uses Entity Framework, which may or may not use Migrations based on your need.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleMembership uses EF code-first for the underlying database access layer.  With EF code-first you use the Package Manager Console for creation and update of the database if you have setup database migration. [Take a look at this article on using database migration with SimpleMembership](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/04/using-code-first-migration-with.html).  There are other ways to handle database migration for production systems but the Package Manager Console is the easiest way to handle it during development.